# How do I write a formula while referencing another sheet in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, microsoft-excel

So I want to do a CountA on Column A and Column B in Sheet Two and divide Column A by Column B in Sheet One to get the percentage totals. Can I write all that in one line?

`=SUM(Sheet!((COUNTA(A2:A516)/(COUNTA(B2:B516))`

Comment: Hey, can you do a sample sheet with some fake data, and what you expect for result ? ty

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Sheet1:

```
=COUNTA(Sheet2!A2:A)/COUNTA(Sheet2!B2:B)
```

You will probably need to then format the result as a percentage (**Format > Number > Percent**).